# child process in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell, child-process

I am trying to compile a c++ file and produce output using node and match it with the answer file that I have. And find the diff between my answer.txt and output.txt , in terminal when I run those command it shows me the line where they both differed 1st time , but when i run through node if both file are same I dont get anything same as my terminal , but when my output.txt file does not matches with answer.txt file I get an Error saying command failed using node , and line where they differed first time in my terminal .

```
 exec(
        `cd ${dirprob} && g++ ${job.filepath} -o testprogram && ./testprogram <input.txt >output.txt && diff output.txt answer.txt ` , 
        
        (error,stdout , stderr)=>{
            if (error) {
                
                return ;
            }
            if (stderr) {
                console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
                return ;
            }
            console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
            return ;
        })
```

above is the code of my exec function

Comment: why dont you use a Makefile for this?

Comment: sorry I did not understood , I wanted to create output.txt depending on the result of the code, and to compare both of them , to me this striked at first , could you please elaborate how to use makefile for this

Comment: I think i need to study makefile , i was not familiar with it

Comment: I mean use a Makefile to compile your c++ code. Its meant for that. Regarding the diffing, that is a different game. If you want to do that in node, sure. But you could also do this in make, even though its not meant for this, it still can be used for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misunderstanding what `error` means in `exec`. It is the return code of the program you ran, and `diff` will return a non-zero code when the files are not equal. So this is not an error in the sense that the command failed. But in your code you are bailing when it happens.

Just remove the `if (error) { return; }`.

Btw, you should probably break down the long `exec` command string, too, and use `cwd` to set the working directory rather than `cd`ing. Ideally you'd have the `diff` call be completely separate so that you can be sure that errors (that I propose to ignore) are indeed coming from that.